# how to update a json field laravel in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

I'm create project CRUD with uploads file using json_encode for uploads file in database. i want to ask how to edit/update json field in database laravel ?

i try using isset($data)? json_encode($data): $sid->file_uploads in public function update() but that code when i update can be replace previous file.

```
    $sid = Sid::find($id);

    if($request->file('file_uploads'))
    {
        foreach($request->file('file_uploads') as $file)
        {
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = 'public/file/'.$sid->employee_name;
            $file->move($path, $name);
            $data[] = $name;
        }
    }

        $sid->employee_sid          = $request->employee_sid;
        $sid->employee_npk          = $request->employee_npk;
        $sid->employee_name         = $request->employee_name;
        $sid->file_uploads          = isset($data)? json_encode($data): $sid->file_uploads;
        $sid->save();
```

i expect the result is file when i upload will add file in DB. for example i uploads 5 file but when i create i just uploads 2 file and when i want to edit i add 3 file and totals file is 5 in DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can resolve, php in the new versions does not support creation of var at runtime, or its if that checks if it has files is resulting in false.

```
$sid = Sid::find($id);
$data = [];

if($request->file('file_uploads'))
{
    foreach($request->file('file_uploads') as $file)
    {
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = 'public/file/'.$sid->employee_name;
        $file->move($path, $name);
        $data[] = $name;
    }
}

    $sid->employee_sid          = $request->employee_sid;
    $sid->employee_npk          = $request->employee_npk;
    $sid->employee_name         = $request->employee_name;
    $sid->file_uploads          = count($data)? json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($sid->file_uploads, true),$data)): $sid->file_uploads;
    $sid->save();
```

Comment: sir. but still same with before. file uploads will replace when i update the new file

Comment: What result of condicion? if($request->file('file_uploads'))

Comment: You has ensure if($request->file('file_uploads')) shall result in true

Comment: the result is for multiple uploads file.

Comment: Try again with     $sid->file_uploads          = count($data)? json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($sid->file_uploads, true),$data)): $sid->file_uploads;

Comment: can i asking other question sir ?

Comment: Yes, but make in new post

Comment: sir pls help. i make a new post "how to show a json field laravel in view blade and edit the json_encode multiple uploads file?"